# Laravel 5.4 - how to put file in the database directory

Tags: php, database, sqlite, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm working on the database restore menu for an application I created, I'm using sqlite for my database, and I want to put my previously backed up database file to the database directory

**backupAndRestore.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/backupAndRestore/restore" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="file-field input-field">
              <div class="btn">
                <span><i class="material-icons">file_upload</i></span>
                <input type="file" name="database" accept=".sqlite">
              </div>
              <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                <input type="text" class="file-path" placeholder="Example: file_name.sqlite" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">restore</button>
          </form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/admin/backupAndRestore/restore', 'DatabaseController@restore');
```

**DatabaseController.php**

```
public function restore(Request $request)
{
    $database = $request->database;
    $file_name = 'database2.sqlite';
    $path = database_path($file_name);

    file_put_contents($path, $database);

    return $path;
}
```

my code works, the file is stored in the database directory, the problem is when I backup my database file size is 22kb, but when I restore it and I check the database directory, the file is 1kb size and when I open using sublime file contents as shown below

[Images](https://i.imgur.com/HobUxnX.png)

which I expect as shown below

[Images](https://i.imgur.com/S9bdMKm.png)

can someone tell where my fault is?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) which inserts the contents in the given file and does not move the file.

If you want to store a file in database path..

```
public function restore(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'database' => 'required|file|mimes:sqlite'
    ]);

    $databaseFile = $request->database;

    $fileName = 'database2.sqlite';

    $databaseFile->move(database_path(), $fileName);

    // return success message...
}
```

For more information uploading files: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files.